# Sending result of Procedure as the body of an email

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a procedure which returns a set of rows.
Similarly, I am using a procedure to send an email whose parameters is as follows :
**SEND_MAIL ( mail_to, mail_from, mail_subject, mail_body, host)**

I have been trying to pass a variable which consists of the result from the **DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE** as mail subject in the SEND_MAIL procedure but I am only obtaining the **last record** of the result which indicates the variables only has the latest inserted value.

I want to receive the **entire result in the mail body.**

```
create OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EVAL_LOG AS
mail_body_v varchar2(4000);
BEGIN

FOR I IN ( select LOG.LOG_DATE,LOG.ACTION,LOG.OLD,LOG.NEW from
dw.EVALUATIONS_LOG LOG
where to_char(log_date,'DD-MON-YYYY')
in (select max(to_char(log_date,'DD-MON-YYYY')) from dw.EVALUATIONS_LOG))
loop mail_body_v:=
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
  ( 'Date : ' || i.log_date
  
|| '  ACTION : ' || i.ACTION
|| '  OLD : ' || i.OLD
|| '  NEW : ' || i.NEW));

end loop;

SEND_MAIL('****@mailid.com',
    'Subject',mail_body_v,'****@mailid.com','host');
end;
```

Output:

```
Date : 16-AUG-22  ACTION : INSERT  OLD :   NEW : 2382382
Date : 16-AUG-22  ACTION : UPDATE  OLD : 175  NEW : 195
Date : 16-AUG-22  ACTION : INSERT  OLD :   NEW : 232323
Date : 16-AUG-22  ACTION : UPDATE  OLD : 195  NEW : 175
Date : 16-AUG-22  ACTION : UPDATE  OLD : 195  NEW : 175
Date : 16-AUG-22  ACTION : UPDATE  OLD : 175  NEW : 195
Date : 16-AUG-22  ACTION : DELETE  OLD : 232323  NEW :
```

Comment: `mail_body_v:= mail_body_v || ... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting value of `mail_body_v` each time you enter loop, thats why only the last result is visible.
Instead of assigning new value to the `mail_body_v` each time it enters the loop, you should add text to the old value.

So instead of: `mail_body_v:= DBMS_OUTPUT...`

you should do it like that: `mail_body_v:= mail_body_v || DBMS_OUTPUT...`

Your code, after required changes could look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EVAL_LOG AS
mail_body_v varchar2(4000);
BEGIN

FOR I IN ( select LOG.LOG_DATE,LOG.ACTION,LOG.OLD,LOG.NEW from
dw.EVALUATIONS_LOG LOG
where to_char(log_date,'DD-MON-YYYY')
in (select max(to_char(log_date,'DD-MON-YYYY')) from dw.EVALUATIONS_LOG))
loop 
mail_body_v:= mail_body_v ||
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
  ( 'Date : ' || i.log_date
  
|| '  ACTION : ' || i.ACTION
|| '  OLD : ' || i.OLD
|| '  NEW : ' || i.NEW));

end loop;

SEND_MAIL('****@mailid.com',
    'Subject',mail_body_v,'****@mailid.com','host');
end;
```